# How to calculate effect of elevation change on vehicle normal force?

Tags: curvature

My name is Ricky and I run a site called Race Optimal.

http://www.raceoptimal.com/about/physics

I'm working on converting the 2D physics model to 3D.  I have an algorithm to calculate a continuous piecewise polynomial for the x, y, and z coordinates.  As the z coordinate changes, more and less normal force is experienced depending on the acceleration relative to the z-axis.  Typically this would be solved by calculating the radius of curvature.  However, since the path is 3D, I'm not sure how to calculate curvature relative to the z axis.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What if you just took a derivative of the polynomial to get the acceleration in the Z direction, then used $F = ma$?

Comment: I think the problem with that approach is that acceleration depends on velocity, and achievable velocity depends on how much the normal force is affected.  If I know the effective radius of curvature I can calculated max velocity explicitly.

Comment: Look at [radius of curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature) for 3D curvature and [curvature of space curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_space_curves)

Comment: Cool question, but it is more about math at this stage. Later you should ask about physics here.

Comment: For some reason I missed the section of the Wikipedia article on space curves when I was researching.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia to the rescue!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_space_curves

Basically, when the 3D curve is in parameterized form, the first derivative with respect to t gives the tangent vector to the path.  The second derivative gives the normal vector pointing in the direction of acceleration due to curvature.  Radius of curvature is then given by

$$
R=\frac{(x'^{2}+y'^{2}+z'^{2})^{3/2}}{\sqrt{(z''y'-y''z')^{2}+(x''z'-z''x')^{2}+(y''x'-x''y')^{2}}}
$$

The radius of curvature relative to the vertical can be found by dividing this total radius by the z component of the unit normal.  The curvature relative to the x and y directions, i.e. for cornering, can be found by dividing by the magnitude of the x and y components combined.  Thus, the effective radius of curvature in for cornering or vertical acceleration with be equal to or larger than the 3D radius of curvature.